# Retrieving query data from four tables using SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have four tables:

- `Customer` (ID, CustomerName, City)
- `Product` (pid, pname, sprice)
- `Orders` (OrderNum, CustomerID, EmpID, orderDate)
- `Sales` (OrderNum, pid, qty, totalAmmount, payed, credit, CreditEndDate)

I want to retrieve data from above four tables using the following query, but I encountered a problem where I can alias the sales table?

```
SELECT 
    Cs.CustomerName, Cs.City, Crs.totalAmount, p.pname, Crs.qty,
    crs.totalAmount, crs.payed, Crs.credit, ord.orderDate,  
    Crs.CreditEndDate 
FROM 
    Customer Cs 
INNER JOIN 
    Orders ord ON Cs.ID = ord.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN
    Product p ON p.pid = Sales Crs.pid 
WHERE
    ord.OrderDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '01/01/2016' 
ORDER BY 
    [CustomerName]
```

Is there any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join `Sales` table

```
SELECT Cs.CustomerName,
       Cs.City,
       s.totalAmount,
       p.pname,
       s.qty,
       s.totalAmount,
       s.payed,
       s.credit,
       ord.orderDate,
       s.CreditEndDate
FROM   Customer Cs
       INNER JOIN Orders ord
               ON Cs.ID = ord.CustomerID
       INNER JOIN Sales s
               ON s.OrderNum = ord.OrderNum
       INNER JOIN Product p
               ON p.pid = s.pid
WHERE  ord.OrderDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '01/01/2016'
ORDER  BY [CustomerName]
```